# Bitmap to vector contour lines in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas

I'm trying to generate dynamic, topographic style contour lines in Javascript.

- I can get a height map from perlin noise.
- I can get a bitmap contour line approximation from that height map from a custom gamma curve or LUT (in theory, but I assume a library exists. I know LUT's are implemented in some Three.JS examples).

The question is how can I generate vector contour lines? I assume I would have to find each pixel of a given value and crawl through the nearest neighbors, then create a bezier curve from the positions.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I've done something like this using [Perlin noise](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/JKEJEG?editors=0010) and pixel manipulation in canvas or [metaballs](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/70a25ae45f75fc5e4360dfa8cceb531d?editors=1010) and pixel manipulation. I think pixel manipulation is the way to go.

Comment: Using a flood fill algorithm will find connected regions with same quantity within tolerance, Write encountered edges to a stack that can be used to trace. With a few webWorkers its near (video) realtime and very usable interactive draw and vectorize, depending on the contour count.

Comment: This article is good: http://thingonitsown.blogspot.com/2019/02/finding-perlin-contours.html